# App restarted and the language changed when I change some permission to deny from setting in Android

Tags: java, android, localization, android-permissions

I'm developing an Android app with two languages (English - Arabic) , my app is an `Activity` that contains `Fragments`
I'm handling changing of the language across the app correctly but guys when the app language is `Arabic` then change any permission to deny from setting and open the app again , my app is restarting and the app language converted to be `English`

I already save the language in the `Sharedpreferences` , language is saved as Arabic correctly and the app works fine in all cases  , but when changing permission from setting to deny , All strings converted to English and views directions change.

I tried to change the local in the `onRestart()` but it doesn't work , so any suggestion to solve this problem ?

If it would help , I'm changing the language in `Splash screen` based on the saved value from sharedpreference

```
 public void setLocal(String lang) {


        Resources res = this.getResources();
        Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
        conf.locale = new Locale(lang);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            conf.setLayoutDirection(new Locale(lang));
        }
        res.updateConfiguration(conf, res.getDisplayMetrics());
        Consts.first_lang_choose = true;
        

    }
```

Comment: It seems you are overriding the Locale / Resources / Context yourself. Where exactly in your app, and how?

Comment: I'm converting it in splash screen , I will post the code in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm changing the language in Splash screen

You need to have Locale override in all your activities. The Android framework can kill your activities (or even your app) and later restore it to the activity where it was, not going though your entry point activity such as a splash screen.

Comment: you mean I need to write the setLocal function in the MainActivity ?

Comment: Yes, also in there

Comment: It worked fine thank you , I have another exception , It worked only if I were in the first fragment , but If I were in other fragment , I get  a no view found for Fragment B .. and the exception is in onStart of the mainActivity

Comment: can you please help me in the above comment ?

Comment: There's a bug in your code. You can post a question and include the necessary details there - code, exception stacktrace etc.

Comment: can you please check my question here 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/71468031/11567530

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if you propperly save the language change even when the app restarts.

It is normal that the app restarts if you revoke a permission from the android settings.

Comment: I already save it in Sharedpreferences , language is saved as Arabic , but when changing permission from setting to deny , All strings converted to English and views directions . I will add this to my question